# How to interact with different android browser (get url)

Tags: java, android, html

I'm searching for a way to interact with different android browsers.
My intention is to get the URL of the website that is opened by the browser.
My app should run in background and give an alert when a specific url is opened, for now this is for testing and to learn more about android.

Is there any way to tell the browser to pass the url-string to my app everytime a new url is entered?
I've already got the idea to implement a local proxyserver wich checks all http-requests for a specific url, but is there a better way?
aditionally this should work with every browser not just the standard one but also eg. firefox or dolphin.

I already searched the last few days but couldn't find an answer....

Comment: This would be a massive, massive security hole if it were possible.

Comment: yeah I know i would be.
but is there any way?
just to clearify, I want to build something like a password safe.
when the url is entered the login form should be filled with the stored data.
Though I'm new to android my first step should be to try to get the url to check if there is login data for the website.

Comment: Not really a security hole, don't store sensitive data in the url.

Comment: @TravisJ It's a security hole in that it would allow a (potentially malicious) app creator to monitor and store your browsing history without your knowledge or permission

Comment: @JRaymond - That is the inherent danger you risk in running code from some chop shop. The security hole that you point out is not here, but in the flawed implementation of mobile apps and apps in general to have too much access to their host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this! Check out http://seleniumhq.org/ for how to automate a web browser.

Comment: but to use this you must use instrumentation.and instrumentation can only be used to test apps that are signed by a common key(if i remember)